# calling a function with document.getElementById(" ").click();

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I have a function which is being used to submit a form automatically with a setTimeout function. All seems to work well with the setTimeout calling the function.

```js
function myFunction(){

   document.getElementById("btn").click();    
}
```

But on the other hand when I try to use

```js
window.onbeforeunload = ExitPage;
 
function ExitPage()
{
    myFunction()
 
    // or myFunction();
}
```

The above does not work, any suggestion?

searching for days..lol

Comment: seeing as the page is in the process of unloading, there's no chance a form can be submitted - maybe `sendBeacon` is the solution? By the way, what does this have to do with PHP? besides nothing

Comment: php tag removed

Comment: hey @JaromandaX thanks so much for the response, it did cross my mind on the unloading. but i've learned by self thought, if i dont come across it  the possibility still there.. the reason i wanted the form to submit were to end a mysql connection for a email verification page but i will look into the sendBeacon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When a user tries to navigate away from the current page (e.g., by clicking a link, closing the tab, or entering a new URL in the address bar), the window.onbeforeunload event is triggered. This event is designed to allow you to warn the user about unsaved changes or other actions that they may want to complete before leaving.

The problem you're encountering is due to browser security restrictions that prevent potentially malicious behaviors. For instance, if the browser allowed arbitrary code (like submitting forms or making asynchronous requests) during the onbeforeunload event, it could be abused by malicious websites to carry out unexpected and unwanted actions as a user tried to leave.

To address your problem, you can:

**Warn the User and Take Action Afterwards:**
If your goal is to give the user a chance to save or finalize their data, you can prompt them and then take the necessary action after they have decided.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "You have unsaved changes! Are you sure you want to leave?";
}
```

With the code above, if the user decides to stay on the page, you can programmatically submit your form or take other actions.

**Reevaluate the Flow:**
It might be worthwhile to reconsider your application's flow. If it's essential to submit data or perform an action when a user tries to leave, you might want to implement an auto-save feature or periodic backups.

**Use Visibility API:**
Another approach is to use the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), which allows you to detect when a user switches to another tab or minimizes the browser. While this won't cover all cases where `onbeforeunload` would be triggered, it might be a suitable workaround for some scenarios.

Remember, any action that could be seen as "interrupting" the user's intent or navigation is likely to run into browser restrictions or be flagged as bad behavior. It's always best to design with the user's intent and expectations in mind.

Comment: thanks @Edgar Reynaga, i will look into what JaromandaX above mentioned, i need this form submit to exit(); a mysql connection if the user didn't input a verification code..